# How to get inputs as Intents using Rasa

Tags: python-3.x, rasa-nlu, rasa-core

How best to create my story to process inputs for the sequence:

1. User greets
2. Bot reply with greeting
3. Bot asks user name
4. User enters name
5. Bot saves user name

How do I process the input without setting a pattern like "My name is Tom" but being able to process "Tom" as a username

Working with rasa-core and rasa-nlu on my local machine running python.

Comment: what "without setting a pattern" means?
You need to train your model on like inputs to detect a username.

Comment: if you want to process "inputs as Intents using Rasa", you can precede input with forward slash (/).
e.g. sending `/greet` will directly fire a greet intent in `rasa_core`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use define an intent `inform`, which looks like that in your NLU training data (be sure to provide more examples (> 10) with names so that the entity recognition works reliable):

```
## intent:inform
- [Tom](name)
- [Lisa](name)
- It is [Tom](name)
- My name is [Bob](name)
```

and than have a story like:

```
## Ask name
* greet
  - utter_greet
  - utter_ask_name
* inform{"name": "A name"}
  - action_save_name
```

Comment: Update Rasa 2.2.9: you also need to edit domain.yml as follows:

Answer (score 0):

Update Rasa 2.2.9: in addition to what Tobias suggested, you also need to edit *domain.yml* and add the following lines:

```
slots:
  name: 
    type: text
    initial_value: "human"

entities:
  - name
```